# Even with using width my css-button doesn't get responsive

Tags: html, css, button, responsive-design

I have to design a newsletter, however my button doesn't get responsive. It is probably because of the class. If I create another outside the class it gets better. The class has no css so why can it change my button.

HTML-Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html\>



    
    Title
    
<!-- stylesheet für das Sende-Button-icon hinzugefügt-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g=="
          crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
    



    <form action="https://adra.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=e2d5faa9b94a0d751d430e84b&amp;id=28f961ba01" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    
            <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
    
                <ul><li><input type="checkbox" value="Herr" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-0"><label for="mce-MMERGE3-0">Herr</label></li>
    
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Frau" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-1"><label for="mce-MMERGE3-1">Frau</label></li>
    
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Anders" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-2"><label for="mce-MMERGE3-2">Keine Angaben</label></li>
    
                </ul>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="mc-field-group">
    
                <input type="text" value="" name="VNAME" class="required" id="mce-VNAME" placeholder="Vorname" required>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="mc-field-group">
    
                <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Familienname" required>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="mc-field-group">
    
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="eMail" required>
    
            </div>
    
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear foot">
    
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_e2d5faa9b94a0d751d430e84b_28f961ba01" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    
            <div class="optionalParent">
                <div class="clear foot">
                    <button name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"><i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i> Senden</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
    
        </div>
    
    </form>
```

CSS-Code:

```
#mc_embed_signup .input-group ul {
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
font: 16px Zilla;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 20px;
text-align: left;

}

#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input[type="text"], #mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input[type="email"] {
background: #ffffff;
border-color: #D9D9D6;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 4px 6px;
min-height: 33px;
max-width: 100%;
-basis: 100%;
font: 13px Zilla;
margin: 10px 0;
}

#mc_embed_signup .optionalParent #mc-embedded-subscribe {
background:  #007960;
color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 24px;
font: 15px Zilla;
border-radius: 3px;
flex-basis: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: 10px;
min-height: 35px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#mc_embed_signup .optionalParent #mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
background-color:  #007960;`
}
```

[image]

I expectet the button to get up to 100%, where the inputs end.

If I remove all the css-code excluding the button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTwBd.png)

Comment: Please format your codes properly.

Comment: Could you describe more what 'my button doesn't get responsive' means?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you wrote an incorrect ID name in the CSS. You wrote `#mc_embed_signup` but correct is `#mc_embed_signup_scroll` as per your HTML.

For making button width full just need to add `width:100%` in the second group of classes in your CSS.

You can simply replace your CSS with the below one for a quick solution.

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll .input-group ul { font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.5; font: 16px ; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; height: 20px; text-align: left;}
#mc_embed_signup_scroll .mc-field-group input[type="text"], #mc_embed_signup_scroll .mc-field-group input[type="email"] { background: #ffffff; border-color: #D9D9D6; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 4px 6px; min-height: 33px; max-width: 100%; flex-basis: 100%; font: 13px ; margin: 10px 0; width: 100%; }
#mc_embed_signup_scroll .optionalParent #mc-embedded-subscribe { background: #007960; color: #ffffff; width: 100%; padding: 0 24px; font: 15px ; border-radius: 3px; flex-basis: 100%; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 10px; min-height: 35px; overflow: hidden; }
#mc_embed_signup_scroll .optionalParent #mc-embedded-subscribe:hover { background-color: #007960; }
```